jooq-codegen-maven plugin unable to parse sql query
I am using jooq in my spring-boot project to generate database objects from sql files with jooq-codegen-maven plugin, but I am getting following error while parsing the queries

Unsupported query type: [23:2] ...
json_data json , PRIMARY KEY (id,"date") )[*]partition by range ("date");

here are my dependencies
<dependency>

            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.11</version>
        </dependency>

maven plugin:
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.19.11</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <generator>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase</name>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <key>scripts</key>
                                    <value>src/main/resources/schema.sql</value>
                                </property>

                                <property>
                                    <key>sort</key>
                                    <value>semantic</value>
                                </property>

                                <property>
                                    <key>unqualifiedSchema</key>
                                    <value>none</value>
                                </property>

                                <property>
                                    <key>defaultNameCase</key>
                                    <value>as_is</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </database>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

sql query:(alloydb postgres)
-- trimmed unnecessary columns from query

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.reg_dereg_new
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "date" date NOT NULL,
    json_data jsonb , PRIMARY KEY (id,"date")
)partition by range ("date");



This is the only way I have to generate objects as I can't connect to db from my local machine so I can't generate object locally.
How to solve this?

The error resolved after i removed partitiong part from the query, as it irrelavent to jooq for generating java objects.

You can also just comment it for jOOQ only without any effect on your PostgreSQL execution, with /* [jooq ignore start] */ partition by ... /* [jooq ignore stop] */, see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-ddl/
